# ¿ Como hacer que la política de cookies se vea en el dispositivo móvil?

Tags: javascript, html, css, interfaz-gráfica

Hola tengo una política de cookies y en el ordenador en la parte de abajo de la pantalla.
Pero en el dispositivo móvil a penas se ve parte del texto, no llegan a verse ni el botón de aceptar ni la información.
He cambiado el height sin éxito, no aumenta de alto y a su vez me modifica el body.
¿ Como puedo hacer para que sea lo suficiente alto como para ver en el móvil ?
No se porque en el ejemplo se ve en la parte de arriba de pantalla, en mi proyecto sale por la parte de abajo.
Espero se distinga, añadí los estilos que me permiten y tuve que quitar parte de ellos. Lo siento, no tengo forma de ponerlo.
Gracias

```css
/* ESTO FUNCIONA GRACIAS AL COMPAÑERO EDGAR GUTIERREZ, EL CUAL ME AYUDO CON BOOTSTRAP*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic');
.navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h2{
    margin: 0; bottom: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
p.lead {
 font-weight: 600;
}

a {
    color: #05110f;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.light {
    font-weight: 400;
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}
.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar-brand {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.navbar-brand h1{
 color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
.nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #444;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
   border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;

}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: none;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}

@keyframes boxSpin{
  0%{
    transform: translate(-10px, 0px);
  }
  25%{
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  }
  75%{
    transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
}


@keyframes shadowSpin{
  0%{
    box-shadow: 10px -10px #39CCCC, -10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
  25%{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px #39CCCC, -10px -10px #FFDC00;
  }
  50%{
    box-shadow: -10px 10px #39CCCC, 10px -10px #FFDC00;
  }
  75%{
    box-shadow: -10px -10px #39CCCC, 10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
  100%{
    box-shadow: 10px -10px #39CCCC, -10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
}

#load {
    background:#ffffff url(../img/spinner.gif) center center no-repeat !important;
    height: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.marginbot-0{margin-bottom:0 !important;}
.marginbot-10{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
.marginbot-20{margin-bottom:20px !important;}
.marginbot-30{margin-bottom:30px !important;}
.marginbot-40{margin-bottom:40px !important;}
.marginbot-50{margin-bottom:50px !important;}

.home-section {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:120;
}
.section-heading {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.section-heading h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.section-heading i {
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.bg-white {
 background: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
 background: #f8f8f8;
}


.bg-dark {
 background: #575757;
}

.text-light {
 color: #fff;
}
.intro {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 background: url(../img/header1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
}

#intro.intro {
 padding:20% 0 0 0;
}

.intro .slogan {
 text-align: center;

}

.intro .page-scroll {
 text-align: center;
}

.brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.intro .slogan h2 {
 color: #FFF;
 text-shadow: none;
 font-size: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-width: 0px;
 border-color: #000;
 border-style: none;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 1px #000;
}
.intro .slogan h4 {
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #000;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .intro .slogan h2 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .intro .slogan h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
.boxed-grey {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 padding: 20px;
}
.team h5 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.team p.subtitle {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.avatar {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.widget-contact {
 text-align: left;
}
.validation {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:13px;
}
#sendmessage {
    color: green;
    border:1px solid green;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#errormessage {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#sendmessage.show, #errormessage.show, .show {
 display:block;
}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 0 ;

}
footer p {
 color: #f8f8f8;
}

.credits, .credits a {
    color: #000;
}
#parallax1{
 background-image: url(../img/parallax/1.jpg);
}
#parallax1:after {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0.7;
 z-index: -1;
}
#parallax2{
 background-image: url(../img/parallax/2.jpg);

}
#parallax2:after  {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0.7;
 z-index: -1;
}
.btn {
 border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-circle {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-circle.btn-dark {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
}
.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #999;
    background: #fff;
}
.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover i,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus i{
    color: #999;
}
.page-scroll .btn-circle i.animated {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}
.page-scroll .btn-circle:hover i.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -moz-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

#text {
    color: #fff;
    background: #ffcc00;
}
#map {
 height: 500px;
}
.btn-skin:hover,
.btn-skin:focus,
.btn-skin:active,
.btn-skin.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid #2897c3;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #28a4c3;
}
.btn-huge {
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 26px;
}
.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
}
@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }
    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
    .intro-text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {

 .team.boxed-grey {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 .boxed-grey {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {

 .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 }

 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .tp-banner-container {
  padding-top:40px;
 }

 .page-scroll a.btn-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
 }

}

html .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.nav.navbar-nav li {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
footer a{
   text-decoration-color: #000;
}

a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bb0912;
}

footer p a{
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>web</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="tex/css">


#barraaceptacion {
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 min-height:40px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 color:#fff;
 z-index:99999;
}

.inner {
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 padding-left:5px;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:12px;
 top:30%;
}

.inner a.ok {padding:4px;color:#00ff2e;text-decoration:none;}
.inner a.info {padding-left:5px;text-decoration:none;color:#faff00;}
  </style>
  <script>
    function getCookie(c_name){
      var c_value = document.cookie;
      var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
      if (c_start == -1){
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      }
      if (c_start == -1){
        c_value = null;
      }else{
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1){
          c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
      }
      return c_value;
    }
    
    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
      var exdate=new Date();
      exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
      var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
      document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }
    
    if(getCookie('tiendaaviso')!="1"){
      document.getElementById("barraaceptacion").style.display="block";
    }
    function PonerCookie(){
      setCookie('tiendaaviso','1',365);
      document.getElementById("barraaceptacion").style.display="none";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
 <!--//BLOQUE COOKIES-->
  <div id="barraaceptacion">
      <div class="inner">
        Esta web utiliza cookies como datos estad&iacute;sticos de su navegaci&oacute;n , en cumplimiento del Real Decreto-ley 13/2012. Si contin&uacute;a navegando consideramos que acepta el uso de cookies.
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok" onclick="PonerCookie();"><b>OK</b></a> | 
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="info">M&aacute;s informaci&oacute;n</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <h1>MIGUEL</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#intro">Casa</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section id="intro" class="intro">
    <div class="slogan">
      <h2>Creamos
        <span class="text_color"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="page-scroll">
      <a href="#service" class="btn btn-circle">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="about" class="home-section text-center">
    <div class="heading-about">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
              <div class="section-heading">
                <h2>Sobre mi</h2>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="service" class="home-section text-center bg-gray">
    <div class="heading-about">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
              <div class="section-heading">
                <h2>Servicios</h2>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">
          <hr class="marginbot-50">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="service-box">
              <div class="service-icon">
                <img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/301orj4.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="service-desc">
                <h5>DOMINIO</h5>
                <p>.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="service-box">
              <div class="service-icon">
                <img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/301orj4.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="service-desc">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
      <div class="container">
          <p>Hola mundo</p>
      </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dices que en desktop se debe ver en la parte de abajo de la pantalla? bueno acabe de correr tu código en mi entorno local y se ve en la parte superior

Comment: Hola @CamiloVasquez, si en mi web se ve abajo, incluso en servidor.                  El problema es que en el celular apenas de distingue, bueno el "ok" y el "mas infrmacion" ni se ven.

Comment: Ya lo solucione con `padding-bottom:60px;` antes probaba y me distorsionaba la barra de herramientas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una solución que se adapta a mobil :

```
<!--ley de kookies-->
<style type='text/css'>.cookie_wrap {width:100%;bottom:10px;left:0.3%;position:fixed;text-align:center;z-index: 999;margin:auto;}.cookie_notice {border: 2px solid #000; display:inline-block;margin: auto;padding:10px;border-radius: 5px;font-size: 12px;text-align:center;font-family:verdana;box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000;background: #fff; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.80); color: #000;}#cookie_button {background: #39C;color: #fff;font: bold 12px arial;padding:4px 10px;border-radius: 7px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;}</style><div align='center' class='cookie_wrap' id='aceptacion'><div class='cookie_notice'><b>En este sitio usamos Cookies... si sigues navegando entendemos que aceptas nuestra política. </b><button id='cookie_button' onclick='PonerCookie();' type='button'>OK</button><a href='http://politicadecookies.com' style='color: #000;' target='_blank'><b> Learn more</b></a></div></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
//*
//Cumplir ley de Cookies escript creado por botxtrem Solution
//2017 botxtrem.com
//*

// verifica que el sessionStorage sea null para mostrar el mensaje
if (sessionStorage.getItem('kool2')== null ){
    document.getElementById('aceptacion').style.display="block";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('aceptacion').style.display="none";
    }

    function PonerCookie(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('kool2',1);
    $('#aceptacion').fadeOut('slow');
}
    //]]>
</script>
```